# Can I deploy a System.Web dependent dnx451 project to Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, dnx, system.web

I am using an asp.net 5 and MVC 6 web application and a class library with a web service (WSDL). I can run the application fine locally on IIS express. I have been able to use localdb as well as Azure db. However, when I attempt to deploy the application to Azure, I get a project.lock.json error, but I have a feeling that's not the actual problem.

Here are the steps I am currently taking from Visual Studio 2015:

- Create a new .Net5 web application.
- Add a new .net4.5 class library project to the solution.
- Add the System.Web and Web Service references to the class library.
- Add the class library as a reference to the .Net5 web app.
- Publish the .Net5 web app to Azure web apps.

**project.json**

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-test-2a8ca243-1965-45cb-b8f8-0e8684188d3e",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug" : "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyTestService": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Web.Services": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

A few things to note, I have actually removed the dnx50 framework injection from project.json. This is because I received compile errors about dnx50 not being able to target system.web (because system.web is not currently part of .net5) when building. The other thing is that project.lock.json appears to be updating properly and adding the system.web and MyTestService dependencies in a few places.

The project will do all the front end dependency stuff fine with gulp and bower. Then I get this message on the output window and the build fails:

```
Copying to output path    
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\TestProject113
C:\TestInstalls\TestProject113\wrap\MyTestService\project.lock.json(1,0): 
Error : The expected lock file doesn't exist. 
Please run "dnu restore" to generate a new lock file.
```

I run dnu restore and the restore succeeds. However when I try to publish it again, I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to do restore on you web project or your wrapped project? I had simmilar problem with wrapped ones and I found out that `dnu restore` had to be done on wrapped project. Try going to C:\TestInstalls\TestProject113\wrap\MyTestService\ with your console and run restore command.

Comment: I had not tried that. While it didn't work immediately, it lead me to the answer. Ty! The project.json in wrap/MyTestService was using `"frameworks": { "net451": {` I changed it to `"frameworks": { "dnx451": {` to match the main app project.json. I ran dnu restore on both wrap and src and I was up able to publish normally.